# Function doesn't return $http response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a function expression and assigned it to scope, the idea being that the function will initiate an $http request, get a property and then return it.

```
$scope.getRequestDigest = function () {
    var url = urlParams['SPAppWebUrl'] + '/_api/contextinfo';
    $http.post(url)
    .success(function (res) {
        return res;
    });
}
```

However when I call $scope.getRequestDigest() it simply returns undefined, presumably because the ajax call hasn't completed yet. Is there any way to delay the return until the $http request is complete? I've tried using the .success() promise but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Read about [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). There is no delaying, since Javascript is effectively a single-thread runtime environment. If you *could* delay, the entire app would freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$scope.getRequestDigest = function () {
    var url = urlParams['SPAppWebUrl'] + '/_api/contextinfo';
    return $http.post(url);
}

var digestPromise = $scope.getRequestDigest();
digestPromise.then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

This way you are actually returning a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which AngularJS implements through the [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service.

If you were to output (`console.log(digestPromise)`) `digestPromise`, you will see that you can all sorts of functions on it, like `success` or `complete`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

`$http.post` returns a promise (see [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)).  In order to use the result, bind `res` to `$scope.res`:

**controller:**

```
$scope.getRequestDigest = function () {
    var url = urlParams['SPAppWebUrl'] + '/_api/contextinfo';
    $http.post(url)
    .success(function (res) {
        $scope.res = res;
    });
}
```

Then, you can use `$scope.res` (or `res` in the template) anywhere you'd like.

After the promise chain is resolved (after `success`), Angular will run a digest cycle and rebind everything on `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use chain promise using `.then`

```
$scope.getRequestDigest = function () {
    var url = urlParams['SPAppWebUrl'] + '/_api/contextinfo';
    return $http.post(url) //this will return a promise
    .then(function (res) {
        return res.data; //on success this will return a data to caller function
    });
}
```

Then the caller function will have call the function and get the data like this

```
$scope.getRequestDigest().then(function(data){
   console.log(data)
   //here you can get data returned from `getRequestDigest` method
})
```